# Why do we have that $\int_S\left|f\right|d\mu = \int_S\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\inf\left|f_n\right|d\mu$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, limsup-and-liminf

**Theorem:** (Fatou's lemma). Let $(f_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of measurable functions with values in $[0,\infty]$. Then $$\int_S\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}f_nd\mu \leq \liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_S f_n d\mu.$$

**Exercise:** Assume that $f, f_1, f_2, ...:S\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ are measurable functions such that

i) There is a constant $M\geq 0$ such that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}, \int_S\left|f_n\right|d\mu\leq  M$.

ii) $f_n\to f$ pointwise.

Use Fatou's lemma to show that $\int_S\left|f\right|d\mu\leq M$.

**Solution:** Fatou's lemma yields that: $$\int_S\left|f\right|d\mu = \int_S\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}\left|f_n\right|d\mu\leq \liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_S f_nd\mu \leq M.$$

**My question:** How do we know that $\int_S\left|f\right|d\mu = \int_S\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}\left|f_n\right|d\mu$ and $\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_S f_nd\mu \leq M$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $f_n\to f$ pointwise implies that $|f_n|\to |f|$ pointwise and consequently $\liminf|f_n|=|f|$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) If $f_n \to f$ pointwise, then also $|f_n| \to |f|$ pointwise, so that
$$
|f(x)| = \lim_n |f_n(x)| = \liminf_n |f_n(x)|
\qquad\forall x\in S.
$$

2) In general, if $(a_n)\subset\mathbb{R}$ is a sequence such that $a_n \leq M$ for every $N$, then $\liminf_n a_n \leq M$ (and also $\limsup_n a_n \leq M$).

Since, by assumption, $a_n := \int_S |f_n| \, d\mu\leq M$ for every $n$, you have that
$$
\liminf_n a_n = \liminf_n \int_S |f_n|\, d\mu \leq M.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Could you elaborate on why $f_n\to f$ pointwise implies that $\int_S \left| f\right | d\mu = \int_S\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}\left|f_n\right|d\mu$?

Comment: Because $f_n\to f$ pointwise implies that $\lvert f_n\rvert\to \lvert f\rvert$ pointwise, which implies that for any $x$, $$\liminf_{n\to \infty} \lvert f_n(x)\rvert = \lim_{n\to \infty} \lvert f_n(x)\rvert = \lvert f(x)\rvert$$ We typically write this as $$\liminf_{n\to \infty} \lvert f_n\rvert = \lvert f\rvert$$ since the two are equivalent as functions.